# target DOM element with React.createPortal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-context

I would like to get the innerHTML of a div with the className "editor" which i am passing in through useContext. Once I receive the innerHTML, I will append it to a div with the className "getcontent". Currently, my code is giving me an error message "Error: Target container is not a DOM element." I have created a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-turing-yxx6j) . Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you pass 'editor' string to the query selector. It's incorrect.

Your `content.editor` is equal to "editor" string.

But when you use `querySelector` you have to use syntax like css selectors (`#` - id, `.` - class).

I think that you have just missed this dot.

```js
document.querySelector('.editor');
```

Full solution:

```
ReactDOM.createPortal(null, document.querySelector(`.${context.editor}`));
```

It works for me now without any errors :)

Another function without dot:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('editor')[0];
```